# Nativescript Angular

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, nativescript

I've developing an app using NativeScript with Angular
I can run it on the simulator but when i open the project in XCode and try to create the archive file I get the following under Apple Mach-O Linker

```
Ld /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/userapp.build/Release-iphoneos/userapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/userapp normal armv7
cd /Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -L/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Mobile/360-    id/userapp/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/internal -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/ios -filelist /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/userapp.build/Release-iphoneos/userapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/userapp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/userapp.build/Release-iphoneos/userapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/userapp_lto.o -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/userapp.app/userapp -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework BEMCheckBox -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreText -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GTMOAuth2 -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework IQKeyboardManager -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QBImagePickerController -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SwiftyCam -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TesseractOCR -framework leveldb -framework nanopb -ObjC -sectcreate __DATA __TNSMetadata /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/metadata-armv7.bin -framework NativeScript -F/Mobile/360-id/userapp/platforms/ios/internal -licucore -lz -lc++ -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework TNSMLKitCamera -framework TNSWidgets -framework Pods_userapp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/userapp.build/Release-iphoneos/userapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/userapp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/userapp-gjxlejnimwmihjbtipwhycprittu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/userapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/userapp.build/Release-iphoneos/userapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/userapp

ld: framework not found BEMCheckBox
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

These are the dependancies I have in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.2.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "^1.0.6",
    "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~5.2.0",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^3.2.4",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-ocr": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^6.0.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
    "xpath": "0.0.27",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
}
```

Can anyone help determine the cause of the problem?
I'm running XCode 9.2 on MacOS 10.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing your platform with `tns platform clean ios` and updating your cocoapods. `BEMCheckBox` is installed via the nativescript-checkbox plugin using a podfile, which may not be copied if you don't clear your platform. You can also try `tns plugin remove nativescript-checkbox && tns plugin add nativescript-checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is your problem `ld: framework not found BEMCheckBox`. You are missing the framework `BEMCheckBox` in your project which is causing the build to fail.

Check out https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox#installation for how to install the framework. If your not sure how to install it, check out CocoaPods (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods). It's a great tool for installing and managing frameworks.